# How to read visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, intellisense

how to read visual studio code suggestion for example by typing "Str"it shows the string and all properties,methods and parameters that starts with "Str" well my question is what is the proper or best way to read them like when it gives suggestions to do forward or complete statement but how come i know what to do next like visual studio suggests me but i confused to read their properties names etc

Comment: It sounds like you're asking *how to read*.  Please elaborate on the actual problem.

Comment: You are referring to whats called `Intellesence`. It gives you a list of potential matches to help you quickly code. You need to know how to actually write the code

Comment: exactly @logixologist help me please i don't know what to type next and how it works

Comment: Which language are you trying to write.... In Visual Studio you can write in VB.NET, C#.NET., F#.NET and then further complicating it your application can be a desktop application, a WPF application (written in XAML) or a web application written in ASP.NET USING VB.NET or C#.NET. Before you can code in Visual Studio you need to decide on a language and then you willl need to find resources to learn that language. Only then will Intellisense help you.

Comment: Its lke trying to write to take a course in a foriegn language using google translate.

Comment: i'm working on C# @logixologist

Comment: @logixologist when i start doing something new for example printing or threading or something else i start confuse on the intellsence that suggests me properties and parameters , i don't know how to implement them and what is properties and what is parameters etc how to recognize them and implement them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this: [Using IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), IntelliSense is the general term for a number of features: List Members, Parameter Info, Quick Info, and Complete Word. These features help you to learn more about the code you are using, keep track of the parameters you are typing, and add calls to properties and methods with only a few keystrokes.

Since you used the C#, there is a document: [Visual C# IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx) to describes the detail information.

If you want to know the type of those List Members, you can know it through the icon before the List Members or you can try to install [the VS 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and there has the filter like the following screenshot, click the specific type and the List Members will display the corresponding members that matches this selected type.
[image]

Comment: yea i got it but i'm trying to tell you that the suggestion it gives i can't understand it their syntax/words are difficult to understand for me how to undersant them ?? if like you said above  there's a document that describes the details can you kindly provide me the resource to get it

Comment: @Jibbo, When you move up or down on the List Members and it popups a little window with the Quick Info. If you want to know the detail information about those List Members, choose it to display, then right click this one and choose ‘Peek Definition’ to know the definition of it like this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmvaz7i4dJALHXWL. The intellisense is just a tool to auto filter the parameters per your typing, quick info about the code, you should have a basic development knowledge before code. Search around the learning video or tutorials about C# language for beginners to start.